# invalid read of size 1 from valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

After I fixed the memory leak, valgrind shows me a bunch of lines errors as the following, and I have no idea how to fix that. Is it because I free more space than I need or something?

line 39:

```
root = importTree(*(argv+1));
```

line 72:

```
 printf("Result found for %d:\n       city: %s\n       state:%s\n", zip, new->city, new->state);

Node *importTree(char *filename) {
    Node *root = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (!new) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory. Ending read.\n");
            exit(1);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        new->city = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXCITYNAME);
        if (!(new->city)) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory. Ending read.\n");
            exit(1);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        new->left = NULL;
        new->right = NULL;
        char *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLINELENGTH);
        if (!line) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory. Ending read.\n");
            exit(1);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        if (fgets(line, MAXLINELENGTH, fp) == NULL) {
            if (!feof(fp)) {
                printf("File reading ended prematurely. Check for errors in the file.\n");
                exit(1);
                fclose(fp);
            }
            free(new->city);
            free(line);
            free(new);
            fclose(fp);
            break;
        }
        char *tmp = strtok(line, ",");
        new->zipCode = atoi(tmp);
        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(new->city, tmp);
        new->city[strlen(tmp) + 1] = '\0';
        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(new->state, tmp);
        new->state[2] = '\0';
        root = addNode(root, new);
        if (!root) {
            printf("Root of tree is still NULL! Ending read.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        free(line);
        free(new->city); \\this is the line 220
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return root;
}
```

Here is valgrind's output:

```
Invalid read of size 1
==7879==    at 0x517FAB4: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==7879==    by 0x5188C98: printf (printf.c:34)
==7879==    by 0x400BBD: main (hw3.c:72)
==7879==  Address 0x5657a30 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 30 free'd
==7879==    at 0x4C2AD17: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7879==    by 0x40103F: importTree (hw3.c:220)
==7879==    by 0x400A31: main (hw3.c:39)
==7879==
==7879== Invalid read of size 1
==7879==    at 0x51ADA99: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1342)
==7879==    by 0x517FA6C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==7879==    by 0x5188C98: printf (printf.c:34)
==7879==    by 0x400BBD: main (hw3.c:72)
==7879==  Address 0x5657a37 is 7 bytes inside a block of size 30 free'd
==7879==    at 0x4C2AD17: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7879==    by 0x40103F: importTree (hw3.c:220)
==7879==    by 0x400A31: main (hw3.c:39)
==7879==
==7879== Invalid read of size 1
==7879==    at 0x51ADAAC: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1342)
==7879==    by 0x517FA6C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==7879==    by 0x5188C98: printf (printf.c:34)
==7879==    by 0x400BBD: main (hw3.c:72)
==7879==  Address 0x5657a36 is 6 bytes inside a block of size 30 free'd
```

Comment: Don't use `sizeof(char)`, there is not way that it would be different than 1. So it's redundant and simply makes the code harder to read and the lines where it appears longer than necessary. And you cenrtainly don't need `malloc()` for a `MAXLINESIZE` use an array, `malloc()` is slow and you really don't need it. And testing for the end of file is  also redundant, you already check if `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: [Also `while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You might `fclose()` the file twice too. You need to check a lot of things before worrying about valgrind apparently.

Comment: @chqrlie: thank you for adding the white spaces, the code was really making me sad.

Comment: Oh, and `fclose(file)` after `exit(1)` will not work at all. Do you understand what `exit(1)` will do?

Comment: @iharob: No, it doesn't make the code harder to read. The well-established idiom fro array allocation is `malloc(N * sizeof element)`. Follow it every time you allocate an array, even if you know that `sizeof element` is guaranteed to be 1. A deviation from this pattern makes code harder to read since it makes reader to stumble and spend time figuring out why `sizeof element` is omitted. While it is easy to figure out, it is still irrelevant and isn't worth spending time on.

Comment: @AnT that is your opinion and I am sure that many others also think that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you `free` the `city` member of the `new` structure after inserting the node in the tree? It belongs to the structure, it will be freed twice when you deallocate the tree.

There are other issues in your code:

- `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong.  In your case, just run forever with `for(;;)` and exit the loop gracefully when `fgets()` fails at end of file.
- You should not use `new` as an identifier, it confuses the code colorizer (and the reader) because it is a keyword in C++. Just call it `node` or `np`.
- The line `new->city[strlen(tmp) + 1] = '\0';` is at best useless, and may cause a buffer overflow.
- indeed, we don't know the values of your array sizes, but you do not check the sizes before calling `strcpy()` to copy line chunks.  This may invoke undefined behavior.
- You should instead use `strdup()` to allocate the correct size for the line fragments and copy the contents in one simple step.
- Similarly, allocating the node **after** a successful `fgets()` would simplify the error cases.
- You do not check the return value of `strtok()`.  Invalid file contents may cause the return value to be `NULL`, invoking undefined behavior instead of a graceful fatal error.

Here is a simpler corrected version:

```
Node *importTree(const char *filename) {
    char line[MAXLINELENGTH];
    Node *root = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAXLINELENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (!node) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory. Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        new->left = NULL;
        new->right = NULL;
        char *tmp = strtok(line, ",");
        if (!tmp) {
            printf("Invalid file contents. Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        new->zipCode = atoi(tmp);
        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        if (!tmp) {
            printf("Invalid file contents. Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        node->city = strdup(tmp);
        if (!(new->city)) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory. Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        if (!tmp) {
            printf("Invalid file contents. Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        tmp[2] = '\0';
        node->state = strdup(tmp);
        if (!node->state) {
            printf("Failed to allocate memory. Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        root = addNode(root, node);
        if (!root) {
            printf("Root of tree is still NULL! Ending read.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (!feof(fp)) {
        printf("File reading ended prematurely. Check for errors in the file.\n");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: I wish this was the only problem, there are too many problems in the code.

Comment: Nice comment about `new`, I used to use it. But it's certainly a BAD IDEA.

Comment: it actually gave me a memory leak if I don't free it.

Comment: LEAK SUMMARY:
==9870==    definitely lost: 150,000 bytes in 5,000 blocks
==9870==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9870==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9870==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9870==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

Comment: @fjidsanfklxingdwsf You do need to free it -- but free it when you free your tree nodes, not when you insert them.  You're just freeing it at the wrong time and place.